# Random walk using petgraph

Tags: rust, graph-algorithm, petgraph

I am trying to implement a random walk on a directed graph using the `petgraph` crate.

So far, I have defined a `RandomWalk` struct which implements the `Walker` trait:

```
extern crate petgraph; // 0.4.13
use petgraph::visit::{GraphBase, Walker};
use petgraph::Direction;

pub struct RandomWalk<G> 
    where G: GraphBase
{
   next: G::NodeId, 
}

impl<G> Walker<G> for RandomWalk<G>
    where G: GraphBase
{
   type Item = G::NodeId; 

   fn walk_next(&mut self, graph: G) -> Option<Self::Item> {
       // Even this deterministic walk does not work:
       graph.neighbors_directed(self.next, Direction::Incoming).next()
   }
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `neighbors_directed` found for type `G` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:50:11
   |
50 |     graph.neighbors_directed(self.next, Direction::Incoming).next()
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `neighbors_directed` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&G : petgraph::visit::IntoNeighborsDirected`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `neighbors_directed`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `petgraph::visit::IntoNeighborsDirected`
```

I don't really understand how the `petgraph` API works, is `GraphBase` not the correct type?

Comment: As the error message states, the correct trait is called `IntoNeighborsDirected`, if you really want to be generic over `G`.  If you just want to get something working, it may be quicker to implement this for a concrete type first (e.g. `Graph`).

Comment: Always try to give us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I edited it, so you can see, what I mean. Now I can copy&paste the code into the playground (better you provide us a playground ;) ) and start solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that the Rust playground supports crates as well - that's a nifty feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quiet clear, if you understand the compiler.
Rust does not assume anything about the type, unless you specify it, e.g. you can't add two types `T` together, unless the implement the [`Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) trait. Then you can write `T + T`.
Your problem is very similar.

You are trying to use the function `neighbors_directed` which is not implemented for `G` (which is bound to `GraphBase` in your example). Instead you have to specify that `G` also must implement the trait [`IntoNeighborsDirected`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.13/petgraph/visit/trait.IntoNeighborsDirected.html) by adding that to your impl block.

```
impl<G> Walker<G> for RandomWalk<G> where G: GraphBase + IntoNeighborsDirected
```

This will tell the compiler, that `G` has the method `neighbors_directed` implemented and you can use it ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=1e63fd476c10f34b547d06aa97423450))